# getInputStream error when making API request

Tags: java, android

I have the following class:

```
public class Api extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private String targetURL;

    private String parameters;

    public final Callback<String> callback;

    public Api(Callback callback)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public String doInBackground (String... params)
    {
        this.targetURL = params[0];
        this.parameters = params[1];

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(this.targetURL);
            connection = this.createPostConnection(url);
            this.sendRequest(connection);
            String response = this.getResponse(connection);
            return response;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String response)
    {
        callback.execute(response);
    }

    private HttpURLConnection createPostConnection(URL url)
    {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            //connection.setUseCaches(false);
            //connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(this.parameters.getBytes().length));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
            return connection;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void sendRequest(HttpURLConnection connection)
    {
        try {
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(this.parameters);
            wr.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getResponse(HttpURLConnection connection)
    {
        try {
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            return response.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

So I am just making an API call. In the main class I have on button click handler written, where I create API object with interface as an argument, receiving the response (the interface's method is being called inside the onPostExecute method).

The problem is that I get the following error here:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Transport.writeRequestHeaders(com.android.okhttp.Request)' on a null object reference
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231)
```

Which means that something happens with the `connection.getInputStream()` method.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're forgetting to call *connection.connect()* on the connection before you access the response.

Comment: I am calling `openConnection()` method - the internet access in manifest was the answer :D